# Deployed GWT web application can't find path specified in properties file

Tags: java, gwt

I have a properties file placed in glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config, the application can read the values specified but It can't find the specified path on the same server deployed, ex:

Props.properties content is:

FilePath=//192.xxx.xxx.xxx/glassfish3/FolderName

My app throws an error that says file or folder does not exist even it is there.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I solved it by:

FilePath=/root/glassfish3/FolderName